# Pregmatch all multiple line with newline

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Then i trying to extract hex code between tags with preg_match_all function i have some problems using regex

```
#<\b(html|body)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\b(html|body)\b>#is
```

work, extract all lines but without  new line simbols? so after converting hex2bin i got unreadable parts

```
#<\b(html|body)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\b(html|body)\b>#im
```

work but extract only single lines, do not extract lines contains new line

So how to extract hex code between tags including all characters.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with REGEX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1519058), use a [DOM parser instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/1519058)...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with: `but extract only single lines lines contains new line do not extracting`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match hex you can use:

```
(?:0x|\$)?[0-9a-f]{5,10}h?
```

This regex matches the hex code from min 5 to max 10 characters.